# Проблемы с cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Почему данный код работает только после 2ой перезагрузки страницы? Сooke создается после первой загрузки страницы, но if блок почему-то не видит cookie во время первой загрузки страницы. Как это можно исправить? Использовать сессии нет возможности. Ps: это упрощённый вариант моего кода с таким же принцем работы.

```
 setcookie("test", "tsst", time()+10, "/");
 if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
echo "ok";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кука не установлена до тех пор, пока ответ не будет отправлен обратно клиенту и не будет доступен на вашем PHP до следующего запроса от клиента после этого.

Можно попробовать так:

```
setcookie('test', $value, time() + 10, "/");
$_COOKIE['test'] = $value;
```

upd: Вы можете установить `$_COOKIE['test']` самостоятельно или использовать промежуточную переменную.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
    $value = $_COOKIE['test'];
} else {
    setcookie('test', $value, time() + 10, "/");  
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое. Не знал о этой особенности куков.

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать подобное для тех куков которые нужно удалить?